# J-PAKE : About Schnorr NIZK proof for ephemeral private keys

Tags: key-exchange, pake

Reading J-PAKE Authenticated Key Exchange Without PKI document :
[J-PAKE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/190.pdf)

> Round 1 : Alice sends out g^x1 and knowledge proof for x1, e.g :
>       To prove the knowledge of the exponent for X = g^x1

My question is : Is then the recipient (the verifier) of g^x1 + NIZK of x1
    able to get the **x1 value** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The whole point of doing a zero knowledge proof (in this case, a non-interactive zero knowledge proof) is that the verifier does not learn any additional information besides the statement that is intended to be proved.

The [Schnorr protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge#Schnorr_protocol) allows to prove knowledge of the discrete logarithm without revealing the exponent. On top of that, the [Fiat-Shamir heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic) can be applied to the protocol to produce a non-interactive version of the proof, still without revealing the exponent.

Comment: Ok, tha'ts what I thougth, though I don't undertand the following in the JPAKE protocol : Alice sends out g^x1 and NIZK for x1 , THEN , in the NEXT round (round2), bob sends out some computation using X1 : how can bob knows about X1 ?

Comment: In round 2, Bob computes $g^{(x1+x2+x3)\cdot x4\cdot s}$. He can compute this without knowing $x1$ and $x2$, but $g^{x1}$ and $g^{x2}$. He simply does $(g^{x1})^{x4\cdot s}\cdot (g^{x2})^{x4\cdot s}\cdot g^{x3\cdot x4\cdot s}$.

Comment: yes right, I've just get that ,reading the J-Pake internet draft, thanks !

Comment: @GLFoxfire Glad to help, and, BTW, welcome to Crypto.SE. If you feel this answer contributed to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted.